# Passing a varchar result of a function as a varchar parameter is giving an error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The first parameter of my stored procedure, usp_LogMessage_Begin, accepts a varchar field as the name of the calling routine. I would like to use the Object_NAME function to return this name as so:

```
EXEC @LogMessageId = usp_LogMessage_Begin OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), 'Begin deleting all records in CBH_REBATBL...'
```

But I get this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_BFAncl01_Reset, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near 'OBJECT_NAME'.
```

This will work:

```
declare @SPName varchar(512)  = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
    EXEC @LogMessageId = usp_LogMessage_Begin @SPName, 'Begin deleting all records in CBH_REBATBL...'
```

but I would rather not create a temporary variable. Does T-SQL not support this type of in-place function evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't support this.

There is a connect item request to upvote for this here: [T-SQL: use scalar functions as stored procedure parameters](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters)